# apt install older version of gcc (not working)

Tags: ubuntu, apt, gcc, version

i want to install a previous version of gcc (7.3.0).
Currently, i have installed gcc in version 7.4.0.

I uninstalled gcc with `sudo apt-get remove gcc; sudo apt-get autoremove` and tried to install the previous version with

```
sudo apt-get install gcc=4:7.3.0-3ubuntu2
```

After installing it, the output of`gcc --version` shows:

```
gcc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

So the installed version of gcc is still 7.4.0.
Why does apt not install the specified version?

Thank you for ur help!

Comment: `This version is not compatible`. I got the package+version(gcc=4:7.3.0-3ubuntu2) while using `sudo apt-cache policy gcc`.

Comment: I got an error, because I did not install the additional required packages. This works now. Thank you for the help. My problem is fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `gcc` package is a metapackage which pulls in the appropriate compiler package; downgrading it won’t downgrade the compiler itself. You need to downgrade `gcc-7`, which is the appropriate compiler package in Ubuntu 18.04:

```
sudo apt install gcc-7=7.3.0-16ubuntu3
```

and any required package.